# C++ - undertanding examples of xvalues

Tags: c++, syntax

I am reading the C++ Reference [article on value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) trying to get a better insight of which expressions can actually be xvalues and what motivates the differences from prvalues and lvalues.

I have some questions on those examples, so I'll go one by one:

> a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`

This is probably the most common case, and I think I mostly understand it. It is basically a conversion to `&&T` (the explicit conversion is covered below) and is used in order to ultimately force the use of overloaded move constructor and assignment which take care of the *actual moving*.

My question here is: is this the only use case for `std::move`? Also, why would I declare something as `int &&a = std::move(42);`?

> `a[n]`, the built-in subscript expression, where one operand is an array rvalue

Ok, here I'm totally lost: what is an *array rvalue* and what is the difference between that and an *array lvalue* (mentioned above in the lvalues examples)?

I guess that the wording of *one operand* refers to this C/C++ syntactic weirdness: `a[n] == n[a]`.

> `a.m`, the member of object expression, where `a` is an rvalue and `m` is a non-static data member of non-reference type

So, if `a` is an expression that happens to be an rvalue, then `a.m` is an xvalue provided that `m` satisfies some conditions.

For example:

```
struct A { int m = 0; };
A a() { return A{}; }
```

Then `a().m` is an xvalue. Is that correct?

> `a.*mp`, the pointer to member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and mp is a pointer to data member

This is possibly the same as the previous example, except using the "pointer to member" feature. Is that correct?

> `a ? b : c`, the ternary conditional expression for some `b` and `c`

*Edited*

This one I find interesting: why is it not of the same type of category as either `b` or `c`?

> a cast expression to rvalue reference to object type, such as `static_cast<char&&>(x)`

Same as with `std::move`. Also, why is `std::move` defined to use `static_cast` and not `dynamic_cast`?

> any expression that designates a temporary object, after temporary materialization. (since C++17)

Which flavor of *temporary materialization* (I know the one about const ref initialization)? Any example for this?

---

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the question police, but I think they usually like only one question per question.

Comment: Array rvalues are not very common, here is an example: `using T = int[2];  T()[1]`  (where `T()` is the rvalue and `T()[1]` is an xvalue by the rule you quoted)

Comment: OK, thank you both. I guess @Eljay is right and this question should be closed. Also, for the record, I found the following to be very useful: https://git.io/JeCYI